# why sequelize orm model can't sync with database

Tags: node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have a some model

```
import DataTypes from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        ...
    });

    return User;
}
```

and use it in my server in function:

```
async function initDatabase() {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.databaseOptions.connectionString, {
        dialectOptions: {
            ssl: {
                require: false,
            }
        },
        models: [
            Room,
            User
        ],
    });
    await sequelize.sync();
}
```

`await sequelize.sync();` - does literally nothing. looks like this sync model with a table in DB, but tables won't creating

what problem with model or it's definition?

i tried `sequelize.models.User.sync();` -> `Cannot read properties of undefined`

Comment: Please show how you import models in the module with `initDatabase`

Comment: @Anatoly `import Room from './models/room.model.js';
import User from './models/user.model.js';`

Comment: But that's just model registration functions and not model themselves. Seems like you should call them with `sequelize` instance like this: `Room(sequelize)` right before calling `sync`

Comment: @Anatoly that's it, everything works now